# How do I derive the type for this function:

Tags: haskell, types, composition

I'm trying to get better at playing "type tetris". I have the functions:

```
(=<<) :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> m a -> m b
zip :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a, b)]
```

And GHCi tells me:

```
(zip =<<) :: ([b] -> [a]) -> [b] -> [(a, b)]
```

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to arrive at that final signature from the first two. My intuition (for lack of a better word) is saying that the first argument of `=<<` namely `a -> mb` is somehow reconciled against the signature of `zip`, and then it should all fall out from that. But I can't understand how to make that leap. Can it be broken down in to a series of easy to follow steps?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It helps to do two things before everything else:

1. put explicit parentheses so that `x->y->z` becomes `x->(y->z)`
2. rename type variables so that there are no clashes

Wit this in mind let's rewrite the types

```
(=<<) :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> (m a -> m b)
zip :: [x] -> ([y] -> [(x, y)])
```

Now match the types. The first argument to `=<<` is `zip`, so `(a -> m b)` is the same as `[x] -> ([y] -> [(x, y)])`.

```
a          ->        m b
[x]        ->        ([y] -> [(x, y)])
```

So `a` is `[x]` and `m b` is `([y] -> [(x, y)])`. Rewriting `->` in prefix notation, we get `-> [y] [(x, y)]`, which is the same as `(-> [y]) [(x, y)]`.

```
m             b
(-> [y])      [(x, y)]
```

So `m` is `(-> [y])` (which is a monad indeed) and `b` is `[(x, y)]`.

So now we know what is `a`, what is `b` and what is `m`. Let's rewrite `(m a -> m b)` in these terms:

```
(m            a)          ->          (m            b)
((-> [y])     [x])        ->          ((-> [y])     [(x, y)])
```

Rewriting in the infix style again, we get

```
([y] -> [x])              ->          ([y] -> [(x, y)])
```

which is, up to variable names, is the same answer GHC is giving you.

Comment: There are some great answers here, but this was the one that caused the penny to drop for me. For some reason I thought the signature of `zip` should completely replace that of `(a -> m b)` - when instead I should have been thinking of the signatures as being equal to each other and solving that way.

Answer (score 8):

`(zip =<<)` is equivalent to `(>>= zip)`, which makes it perhaps a bit more readable. Either way, `zip` occupies the `(a -> m b)` slot in those functions, as you've correctly observed.

One more intuitive transformation to make is thinking about the arity of `=<<`. It "takes" two parameters, so if we apply it to one, we should only be left with one more. Hence, the signature `([b] -> [a]) -> [b] -> [(a, b)]` is an unary function!

```
(zip =<<) :: ([b] -> [a]) -> ([b] -> [(a, b)])
             ------------    -----------------
                 m a'                m b'
```

So what's `m`? The Monad instance exists for functions `(r ->)` (or, alternatively, `(->) r`). So in this case `r :: [b]` (and thus `m :: ([b] ->)`), `a' :: [a]` and `b' :: [(a, b)]`.

Consequently, `zip` fits just as we asserted at the beginning:

```
a'  -> m b'                    -- substitute [(a,b)] for b'
a'  -> m [(a, b)]              -- substitute [a] for a'
[a] -> m [(a, b)]              -- substitute ([b] ->) for m
[a] -> ([b] -> [(a,b)])

[a] -> [b] -> [(a,b)]
```

Answer (score 3):

You just write them down one under another, with vertical alignment as an aid, while renaming the type variables consistently so there's no accidental capture:

```
(=<<) :: Monad m => (a1  ->     m    b1       ) -> m a1 -> m b1
zip   ::             [a] -> ([b] ->  [(a, b)])
                     [a] -> ([b] ->) [(a, b)]
                     [a] -> (->) [b] [(a, b)]
-----------------------------------------------------------
               a1 ~ [a] ,  m ~ (->) [b] ,  b1 ~ [(a, b)]               (*)
-----------------------------------------------------------
(zip =<<) :: Monad m =>                            m a1 -> m b1
                                          ((->) [b]) a1 -> ((->) [b]) b1
                                            ([b] -> a1) -> ([b] -> b1)
                                           ([b] -> [a]) -> ([b] -> [(a, b)])
                                           ([b] -> [a]) ->  [b] -> [(a, b)]
```

provided that `Monad ((->) [b])` instance exists. Which it does:

```
> :i Monad
class Monad (m :: * -> *) where
    .......
instance Monad ((->) r) -- Defined in `GHC.Base'
```

If we follow the types in the specific case of function monad, we can see that `(g =<< f) x == g (f x) x`, and so

```
(zip =<<) f xs = zip (f xs) xs
```

from which it's easier to *see* its type's meaning.

---

`(*)` is the [substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_(logic)) resulting from the successful [unification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science)) of the types `a1 -> m b1` and `[a] -> [b] ->  [(a, b)]` (which is `[a] -> ([b] ->  [(a, b)])`, when fully parenthesized, because `->`s in types associate to the right). Or in fully prefix form,

```
    (->)  a1   ( m            b1       )
    (->)  [a]  ( ((->) [b])   [(a, b)] )
```